# How to configure multiple filters from separate osgi bundles on JAX-RS runtime setting different priority?

Tags: java, servlets, filter, jersey, osgi

Scenario

Filter A -

- Implements com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter - lives on Bundle 1
- Registered in JAX-RS runtime through @Provider    annotation
- Works as expected.

Filter B -

- implements javax.servlet.Filter - lives on Bundle 2
- It just logs the server response time through chain.doFilter() method.
- I tried to register this filter with @Provider annotation and tried again with entry in web.xml, but servlet container avoids to see this filter in either case.

Webapp-

- It does not live neither of Bundle 1 or Bundle 2, more appropriately it is a separate bundle packaged as war file.
- None of the filters have registry on web.xml.

What I have done so far

- Tried to register the Filter B with @Provider annotation without entry in web.xml,
- Tried to register the filter with entry in web.xml without @Provider annotation
- Tried to register the filter with both @Provider annotation and entry in web.xml

But, none of the options are working.

Problem I am trying to solve:

- Tell webapp to recognize filter B through @Provider annotation or even with entry in web.xml (but it is coming from different bundle, and webapp is not built as a bundle so I can not ask to import any package from other bundles)
- Filter A must act before Filter B

I can not change the way Filter A is configured or behaves, however I am free to choose any implementation for Filter B as long as above criteria are met.

Any example, pointer, link or suggestion will help.